# Eliminate redundant sets of table records whose set designations differ

Tags: t-sql

Logically, I have values for each set:

- Set A:  1, 2, 3
- Set B:  1, 2, 3
- Set C:  4, 5
- etc...

Table structure:

```
Set   Value  (Row)
---   -----  -----
 A      1      1
 A      2      2
 A      3      3
 B      1      4
 B      2      5
 B      3      6
 C      4      7
 C      5      8
```

I want to eliminate redundant set **B**, i.e., remove rows 4, 5 and 6.

*But more generally*, remove any set whose members are identical to another set, leaving just one representative set for the members.

For something so simple, the SQL escapes me...

Conceptually, it would be something like obtaining a checksum across the values within the set, but over the respective rows, not across columns.

Comment: will you have 2 row with same `Set` and `Value` ? like `(D - 1 - 9) & (D - 1 - 10)`

Comment: No, it will be a unique member list for each set.

Comment: I suppose I could build a checksum with `STRING_AGG` function but was trying to conceive of something more "pure" from a relational standpoint.

Comment: why do you expect Set B to be deleted instead of Set A?

Comment: @YairMaron good observation - it's arbitrary, so it would be a `FIRST_VALUE` or some other function/grouping mechanism which yields only a single set.  Doesn't necessarily matter whether it's A or B.

Comment: this might help https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/high-performance-relational-division-in-sql-server/

Comment: @Squirrel - thank you, this will take some time to digest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the Sets to delete using this query:

```
WITH SetGroups
AS
(
    SELECT      SetName,
                (
                    SELECT      SQ.SetValue
                    FROM        SetsAndValues   AS  SQ
                    WHERE       SQ.SetName      =   T.SetName
                    ORDER BY    SQ.SetValue
                    FOR         JSON PATH
                )   AS          SetValues
    FROM        SetsAndValues   AS  T
    GROUP BY    SetName
)

SELECT  CurrentGroup.SetName
FROM    SetGroups   AS  CurrentGroup
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    SetGroups           AS  PrevGroup
            WHERE   PrevGroup.SetName   <   CurrentGroup.SetName
            AND     PrevGroup.SetValues =   CurrentGroup.SetValues
        )
```

It's not the most efficient way,
but it's a small and elegant query.

you can simply modify this statement to delete instead of selecting.